# Convert byte to sbyte without changing bits in C#

Tags: c#, casting, unsigned, signed

I want to convert a byte to an sbyte, without changing any bits.

```
byte b = 0x84;
sbyte sb = unchecked((sbyte)b);
Console.WriteLine("0x" + Convert.ToString(b, 16));
Console.WriteLine("0x" + Convert.ToString(sb, 16));
```

The result of this will be:

```
0x84
0xff84
```

I understand what the result means and why it happens. However, I cannot seem to find out what I can do to avoid this behaviour. How can I copy the actual binary value of a byte and get it inside an sbyte?

Comment: Wont the bits be different because sbyte uses two's complement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bit's are not changing between `b` and `sb` at all.  This behavior is coming from [`Convert.ToString()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.tostring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  There just isn't an overload of `Convert.ToString()` that takes an `sbyte` and a base.  The closest match would be [`Convert.ToString Method (Int16, Int32)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1kwkfdz(v=vs.110).aspx).  So `sb` is being sign extended to 16 bits.

Answer (score 0):

Using `ToString` in general produce less surprising results and don't involce unexpected conversions (like `sbyte` -> `short` as described in shf301's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30227860/477420)).

```
byte b = 0x84;
sbyte sb = unchecked((sbyte)b);
Console.WriteLine("0x" + b.ToString("x"));
Console.WriteLine("0x" + sb.ToString("x"));
```

Or just use format directly:

```
String.Format("0x{0:x}",((unchecked ((sbyte)0x84))))
```